# Set on undefined number of list

Tags: python, list, numpy, set

it is possible to do this construction:

```
v = [np.array([(4,'3'),(5,6)]),np.array([(4,'a'),(5,'b')])]

set(v[0][:,0]) & set(v[1][:,0]) #this one
```

not knowing in advance the length of v?

Many thanks

Comment: What is the problem? What happens, what should happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are looking for the intersection of all the items in the `v` list you can loop through like this:

```
a = set(v[0][:,0])
for i in range(1,len(v)):
    a = a.intersection(v[i][:,0])
```

You can also rewrite it in one-liner format:

```
a = set(v[0][:,0]).intersection(*[x[:,0] for x in v[1:]])
```

Comment: It's even simpler than that, `set`'s `intersection` method takes varargs, and it doesn't require them to be `set`s themselves (just iterables) so you don't need to explicitly convert any but the first element to `set`. All you need is `a = set(v[0][:,0]).intersection(*[x[:,0] for x in v[1:]])` (it runs faster too, with no unnecessary temporary `set`s).

Comment: edit with the tips of @ShadowRanger and to mee seems a good answer